# Mysql-foreign keys and array

Tags: mysql

I have two tables. One is Category and the other one is Products. The problem is that one product can have more than one Category and I don't know how to do it.

I've related the tables with a foreign key 1:n.

Thanks

Comment: sounds like your typical many to many relationship. You should create an intermediate table to resolve it. Google it

Comment: You create `CategoryProduct` *link* table.

Comment: The question was marked a duplicate by a 3-2 majority, but two of the votes were "Unclear what you're asking". I don't know whether this is a duplicate or not, because you haven't explained what you're trying to accomplish or what the problem is. Please read this advice on asking good questions: [[ask]], [[Writing the perfect question](http://tinyurl.com/stack-hints)]. Pay special attention to the "Golden Rule", though I highly advise you to read the entire article.

Answer (score 3):

You'd need another table, maybe called ProductCategories.
Each row contains a foreign key to a product and a foreign key to a category.
When you want to find the categories for a product, query for all ProductCategories with that product ID.

Answer (score 2):

You should create 3 table and related them together, something like this:

```
Table: Items
Columns: ID, Item_ID, Item_Title, Content

Table: Tags
Columns: Tag_ID, Tag_Title

Table: Items_Tags
Columns: Item_ID, Tag_ID
```

- Item_ID is a foreign key in Items table.
- Items_Tags is a correlation table.

And for example this code prints all x tags:

```
SELECT * FROM items i 
LEFT JOIN item_tags it ON i.item_id = it.item_id
LEFT JOIN tags t ON t.tag_id = it.tag_id
WHERE tag_title = 'x'
```